# How to split a list of integers into two groups of integers with minimal difference of their sums?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I don't know if this is a duplicate, but Google search returns nothing relevant as usual.

So I have a list of integers, which represents the lengths of segments. And I want to split the list of integers into two lists of integers, such that the difference between the sum of lengths of the groups is minimal.

This is about my GUI program:

[image]

I created the program completely by myself, the program is nearing its completion, I will post it to Code Review when it is complete. I developed each part separately, and now I am trying to improve the layout, to minimize unused area inside the window.

This is a rectangle packing problem, but because the height of the parts are equal, this is simplified to a line packing problem. I only need to split them into two rows and minimize the width difference of the rows.

By the way, many parts of the GUI is controlled by a thread and they animate if triggered. And that is a live Tic Tac Toe game between two AIs I wrote. You can see my program in action [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlSLfhIbyYVEJQUQEFxOugi7DcbjX6yJ/view?usp=sharing).

So I tried to solve the problem, and I did find a solution, but that solution is extremely inefficient, it takes 282240 iterations to find the solution for just 8 items.

My mathematics isn't very good, so I just chose the most direct approach, I just generated every permutation of the sequence, then split each permutation into every possible pairs of sub-lists by index slicing, and then calculate the absolute difference and store the pairs and corresponding difference in a dictionary, and then find the minimum.

```
from itertools import permutations

lengths = [240, 255, 270, 240, 220, 230, 420, 470]

items = {}

for perm in permutations(lengths):
    for i in range(1, 8):
        a = perm[:i]
        b = perm[i:]
        items[(a, b)] = abs(sum(a) - sum(b))

min(items.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

I got this:

```
(((240, 270, 240, 420), (255, 220, 230, 470)), 5)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you use the fact that you want the sum of each half to be as close to half the sum of the whole thing as possible?

Comment: 'I did find a solution, but that solution is extremely inefficient, it takes 282240 iterations to find the solution for just 8 items' You could 'brute force' it in 2^8 = 256 iterations, so I don't know what you were doing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe this question is better asked on the stack exchanges for Computer Science or Theoretical Computer Science. the problem isn't programming, it's logic/theory/algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using dynamic programming.

```
def split (lengths):
    path = {0: [-1]}
    target = sum(lengths) // 2
    for i in range(len(lengths)):
        next_path = path.copy()
        value = lengths[i]
        for prev_value, prev_path in path.items():
            next_value = value + prev_value
            if next_value <= target and next_value not in next_path:
                next_path[value + prev_value] = [i, prev_path]
        path = next_path

    group_a = []
    group_b = []
    path_data = path[max(path.keys())]
    for i in range(len(lengths) - 1, -1, -1):
        if i == path_data[0]:
            group_a.append(lengths[i])
            path_data = path_data[1]
        else:
            group_b.append(lengths[i])

    return (list(reversed(group_a)), list(reversed(group_b)), sum(group_b) - sum(group_a))


lengths = [240, 255, 270, 240, 220, 230, 420, 470]
print(split(lengths))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have only two rows, as the image depicts, your problem can be framed as the optimization variant of the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)- the problem of taking a multiset of integers (widths in your case) and partitioning them into two subsets where the difference in the sum of their elements (combined widths) is minimized.

There are a handful of approximation algorithms, and there are some exact algorithms as well. The problem is NP-hard, but given the number of elements you've shown above, the problem size should be small enough to be a non-issue. If you want either a very precise / exact solution or want an anytime-algorithm, I'd suggest the Complete Karmarkar-Karp algorithm.

In your particular case, I would instead probably opt for the [pseudopolynomial time number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudopolynomial_time_number_partitioning) algorithm. You don't have many elements, so that part won't cause any memory issues, it would only be the magnitude of the numbers (the element widths) that could be problematic. If the numbers are too big, I would just round them to the nearest X pixels, then divide all the widths by X, to get smaller numbers (at the cost of some accuracy, unless you actually resize the components to truly be a multiple of X pixels wide).

One last thing: if you want padding between the elements, you'll need to include that in the widths as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I posted the question I haven't given it much thought and I absolutely didn't do my best. I just tried a lame approach to ask the question, because I know it would be very hard to find the exact solution for n elements in much less than 2<sup>n-1</sup> iterations.

But now I have given it another try and found two better solutions. One is the most efficient way I have found to get the exact solution, and the other one is a very efficient method to find a good approximation.

```
                                       1

                                    1    1

                                  1    2    1

                               1    3    3    1

                             1    4    6    4    1

                          1    5    10   10   5    1

                        1    6    15   20   15   6    1

                     1    7    21   35   35   21   7    1

                   1    8    28   56   70   56   28   8    1

                1    9    36   84  126  126   84   36   9    1

              1    10   45  120  210  252  210  120   45   10   1

           1    11   55  165  330  462  462  330  165   55   11   1

         1    12   66  220  495  792  924  792  495  220   66   12   1

      1    13   78  286  715  1287 1716 1716 1287 715  286   78   13   1

    1    14   91  364  1001 2002 3003 3432 3003 2002 1001 364   91   14   1

 1    15  105  455  1365 3003 5005 6435 6435 5005 3003 1365 455  105   15   1
```

The above is the Pascal's Triangle. Each number represents the total number of ways to choose c elements from a population of r without duplication, in which c is the index of the column the number is located, and r is the row index where the number is, and the indices start at 0.

The total possible ways to choose from n elements is 2<sup>n</sup>.

Now as you can see, the triangle is symmetric and the groups are exclusive, meaning if you choose a elements you automatically know the other n - a elements that weren't chosen. So I just have to generate all possible combinations of the sample with length i, where 1 <= i <= n // 2, and then find the pairs with minimum sum difference.

This method needs half of the nth row of the Pascal's Triangle iterations to find the solution for n elements.

The series is:

```
In [2734]: [sum(row[:i // 2 + i % 2]) for i, row in enumerate(pt.data, start=1)]
Out[2734]: [1, 1, 3, 4, 11, 16, 42, 64, 163, 256, 638, 1024, 2510, 4096, 9908, 16384]
```

I haven't given it a closer look, but the series is more or less 2<sup>n - 1</sup>.

The other method is much simpler, it finds a solution in O(log n + n) time, but the solution isn't the best. The first step is to sort the elements in reverse order, such that greater numbers are listed before lesser numbers.

This is to minimize the impact of later numbers, so they don't affect the difference between two lists very much even if the path isn't optimal.

The next part is very simple, make two empty lists. Then, for each number, calculate the absolute difference between the sum of one list plus the number and the sum of the other list. And append the number to the list that would make the smallest difference.

This solution makes the optimal decision at each junction, but it doesn't find the global optimal.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def even_bisect(s):
    s = list(s)
    total = sum(s)
    choices = chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, i) for i in range(1, len(s) // 2 + 1))
    triples = []
    for choice in choices:
        other = s.copy()
        for e in choice:
            other.remove(e)

        triples.append((choice, tuple(other), abs(2 * sum(choice) - total)))

    return min(triples, key=lambda x: x[2])


def even_partition(numbers):
    assert len(numbers) >= 2
    numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    for n in numbers:
        d1 = abs(s1 + n - s2)
        d2 = abs(s2 + n - s1)
        if d1 <= d2:
            l1.append(n)
            s1 += n
        else:
            l2.append(n)
            s2 += n

    return l1, l2
```

```
In [2738]: lengths = [240, 255, 270, 240, 220, 230, 420, 470]

In [2739]: %timeit even_partition(lengths)
4.68 µs ± 100 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [2740]: %timeit even_bisect(lengths)
167 µs ± 1.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [2741]: even_bisect(lengths)
Out[2741]: ((240, 270, 240, 420), (255, 220, 230, 470), 5)

In [2742]: a, b = even_partition(lengths)

In [2743]: a, b, abs(sum(a) - sum(b))
Out[2743]: ([470, 255, 240, 220], [420, 270, 240, 230], 25)
```